# External node color in Gephi

Tags: graph, gephi

I'm trying to create a graph in `Gephi`. This graph is undirected and has over 100 nodes. I would like to color the nodes in this graph according to my convenience. Say I'd like to color the nodes in 9 different colors. For doing this, I downloaded a plugin to `Gephi` which may be found [here](https://marketplace.gephi.org/plugin/give-color-to-nodes/).

Though the plugin works, I still have to go and enter the color value for every single node manually. There doesn't seem to be a way to do this programatically. And I'd have to create about 10 such graphs, so that means a lot of manual labor.

Can someone help me out with this problem? Does someone know a better way to have custom colors for each node generated programatically? At this point, I'm generating a `.gdf` file, the format looks something like [this](http://changelog.ca/log/2013/03/09/gdf).

I also know that `Gephi` is quite buggy, is there any other `graph visualization` software that I can use? Out of the other usual things that one does to the graph, I definitely want the capability to set `edge weights`. In other words, I'd like to make the edges thicker if the edge weight is more and vice-versa.

I can't use `D3` coz I don't know `Javascript`. I looked into using `GraphViz` but it seems like it requires a lot of manual manipulation of the graph file. I'd like to have something that I'm able to generate programatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What seems to be working is to add a column named `color VARCHAR` where you add the color hex value prepended with the `#` sign and no quotes.

Example:

```
nodedef> name,label,color VARCHAR
a,"Apple",#00ffdd
b,"Banana",#00ddff
c,"Cherry",#dd00ff
d,"Did it!",#0012ca
e,"Ed 209",#121212
edgedef> node1,node2,weight
a,b,2
b,c,30
b,d,0.4
d,e,200
```

**Edit:**

For a more informed answer take a look at the [Gephi documentation](https://gephi.org/users/supported-graph-formats/gdf-format/). The color values in the link are rgb triples but I tried with hex and it worked